# django saving database works, but returns 500 error?

Tags: python, database, django, save

I am straight up confused. I will admit to being a newb, but this should work.
See code below. As written the .save() line is commented out.

When i run this, everythings works fine and as expected, data not saved and 'g' is returned.

If i uncomment the .save() line

The table entry is saved, but a 500 error is return.

Any help much appreciated.

```
def register_new_poll(request):
new_poll_name = request.POST.get('n','d')
new_poll_password = request.POST.get('w','')
new_poll_port = request.POST.get('p','d')
new_poll_ip = request.POST.get('i','d')
new_poll_duration = request.POST.get('d','d')
if new_poll_name != 'd' and new_poll_port != 'd' and new_poll_ip != 'd' and new_poll_duration != 'd':
    try:
        poll.objects.get(name=new_poll_name)
        return HttpResponse("Already In Database");
    except poll.DoesNotExist:
        new_poll = poll(name=new_poll_name,ip=new_poll_ip,port=new_poll_port,password=new_poll_password,duration=new_poll_duration,last_contact_time=datetime.now(),users_at_last_contact=0)
        write_poll_list()
        #new_poll.save()
        return HttpResponse("g");
    except:
        return HttpResponse("b");
        pass
else:
    return HttpResponse("b");
```

Comment: **ERROR LOG ERROR LOG ERROR LOG**

Answer (score 1):

`ip` is a field in `poll`. See line 12 of your paste.

Comment: Sorry, i see my issue now, it was an underlying issue with my code  (Hard to see due to my lack of debuggin experience.)